# Redirect Oracle Apex running on port 8080 to port 80

Tags: apache, port, oracle-apex, virtualhost

I have Oracle Application Express running on http://localhost:8080/apex

I also have apache2 installed - how can i redirect http://localhost:8080/apex to

http://localhost/apex or http://localhost/ ?

Does this has something to do with virtual hosts, mod_rewrite or mod_proxy ?

Comment: You have to install a reverse proxy in front of webserver to redirect ports 8080 to 80 or you can use mod_proxy and make sure that your Apache is also listening on port 80 or you can edit your Apache ports and restart it. 
I use Ubuntu with Apache2.4, look inside /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Answer (score 0):

fixed by checking if the following modules are loaded: `$ httpd -M`

- mod_proxy
- mod_proxy_http
- mod_proxy_balancer
- mod_lbmethod_byrequests

else enabling them by uncomenting **#** on */etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf*

and creating */etc/httpd/conf.d/default-site.conf* with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```